# Can git ignore a file remotely, while including it locally?

Tags: git, tfs, gitignore

I am working on an ASP.NET project where I need to have connectionStrings to connect to databases when I am developing locally on my desktop, but do not want to check those into the tfs repository on the web.  It's easy enough to exclude the ConnectionStrings.config file by putting it in the gitignore file.  But this also keeps it from being saved in my local copy of the branch I'm working on, so every time I switch between branches locally, my config file disappears.

Is there some way to commit locally but ignore remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem.  This project has several development branches, and not all of them had ConnectionStrings.config added to their .gitignore.  So someone was working in one of those branches using the ConnectionStrings.config to connect to the database, and when they checked in their code, they also checked in the config file.

The solution had two parts.  First we had to update the .gitignore of all active development branches so they would ignore the config file.  Then we had to remove the file from that branch's cache.  There was not an obvious way to do so through Visual Studio's Team Explorer, so we ended using the `--cached` option on the command line.

```
git rm -r --cached .\ProjectName\ConnectionStrings.config
```

Fortunately there were only a couple of branches which were in this state, and it was fairly easy to fix them, sync them up with the origin, and get everyone's local branches fixed as well.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some way to commit locally but ignore remotely?

No.

More precisely, not the way you're thinking.  What you *can* do becomes obvious when you realize that, to some extent, Git doesn't care about *files* after all.  What Git cares about—and transfers from repository to repository—are *commits*.  The important part of this, to the Git algorithms that work with the commit graph, are the commits and their parent / child relationships.  Files simply come along for the ride.

Suppose you start out with some set of commits in your repository, which you copied from some other repository (so that the other repository also has these two branches):

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master
         \
          o--o   <-- develop
```

Each round `o` here represents a commit.  You make a new branch `work` that points to the *same* commit that `develop` points to:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          o--o   <-- develop, origin/develop, work (HEAD)
```

(The `origin/*` names are you Git's way of remembering what your Git saw on *their* Git, so as long your Git has not picked up anything new from them, your `origin/*` names still point to these same commits.)

Now you do some work on the new branch and commit.  Let's call this new commit `A` so that we can talk about it (in reality it has some big ugly hash ID):

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          o--o   <-- develop, origin/develop
              \
               A   <-- work (HEAD)
```

If you `git push` from your Git repository, the only new *commit* you can offer them is `A`.

Commit `A`'s actual ID, the big ugly hash, *depends on* everything *about* commit `A`: this includes all the files attached *to* commit `A`, and the fact that the commit to which your `develop` points is commit `A`'s parent.

If you give commit `A` to some other Git, you are obligated to give them every *file* that goes with commit `A`.  If they don't have all the files, they don't have commit `A`.

You *can* make a new commit—let's call this `A'`—that's a whole lot *like* `A`, only slightly different.  Let's make `A'` such that it does not have the file.  Its parent is the same as `A`'s parent, though, and it has all the *other* files—remember, every commit is a complete snapshot of all files—that `A` has.  Let's put `A'` on `develop` by doing it with `git checkout develop` and then copying `A` except that we omit the one file:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          o--o   <-- origin/develop
             |\
             | A'  <-- develop (HEAD)
             \
               A   <-- work
```

Now you can have your Git call up the other Git and offer it, not `A`, but `A'`, via your name `develop`.  If they choose to accept it, your Git will now remember that *their* `develop` points to `A'`.

This particular method is rather painful to use.  It's not the way to go, if you can possibly find some other way.

Comment: Thanks, @torek.  This is definitely more painful and complicated than would be worth it for what I'm trying to accomplish.  But I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The ignored files stay in place if you switch branches. If you add the ConnectionStrings.config file to `.gitignore` on all of your branches (or to a common ancestor), it should always be present (until you do a full `git clean`).

One problem is that if a new person clones for the first time, the file is not present. For this case some people have a template example configuration file like `ConnectionStrings.config.example` with some fake example data, which you commit (not ignore). And after you clone for the first time do a `copy ConnectionStrings.config.example ConnectionStrings.config` and modify the real config.

Another solution to this (although somewhat ad hoc) is that if you have 3 developers working on that site, you could have a single ConnectionStrings.config with multiple connection strings of their local environments with different names say "BobDevDB", "AliceDevDB", "JohnDevDB", and each name prefix resembles their development computer name or their Windows user name so that you can in runtime pick the right connection string. This way you don't have to ignore anything, and it always works.